# O(1) std or boost list concatenate

Tags: c++, list, boost, std

Is there a data structure, such as `std::list`, that allows O(1) concatenation of one list to the end of another? I.e. the final item in list A is linked to the first item of list B?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, [std::list::splice()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice) allows you to concatenate two std::list's in constant time.

Comment: @RiaD: that's only for the version which moves a subset of items from the other list (specified by the pair of iterators).

Comment: @RiaD then use the first or second version and have it in constant time ;-)

Comment: Thanks. This example was also helpful: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/splice/